# Problem with RVM and gem that has an executable

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, rvm

I've recently made the plunge to use RVM on Ubuntu.

Everything seems to have gone swimmingly...except for one thing. I'm in the process of developing a gem of mine that has a script placed within its own bin/ directory, all of the gemspec and things were generated by Jeweler.

The bin/mygem file contains the following code: -

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  require 'mygem'
rescue LoadError
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'mygem'
end
app = MyGem::Application.new
app.run
```

That was working fine on the system version of Ruby.

Now...recently I've moved to RVM to manage my ruby versions a bit better, except now my gem doesn't appear to be working.

Firstly I do this: -

```
rvm 1.9.2
```

Then I do this: -

```
rvm 1.9.2 gem install mygem
```

Which installs fine, except...when I try to run the command for mygem

```
mygem
```

I just get the following exception: -

```
daniel@daniel-VirtualBox:~$ mygem 
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- mygem (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mygem-0.1.4/bin/mygem:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/mygem:19:in `load'
    from /home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/mygem:19:in `<main>'mygem
```

**NOTE: I have a similar RVM setup on MAC OSX and my gem works fine there so I think this might be something to do with Ubuntu?**

Comment: Check `rvm info` and make sure all the PATH, Ruby and Gem info passes a sanity check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```
rvm 1.9.2 gem install mygem
```

is different than how I do my installs of gems inside RVM.

Try:

```
rvm 1.9.2
gem install mygem
```

You might also want to try doing `gem pristine mygem` which will tell Gems to remove the executable and recompile it for the current Ruby.

Another thought: Were you previously using Ruby 1.8+, and just changed to Ruby 1.9+? In Ruby 1.9 the `require` acts differently when loading modules that are relative to the calling code, say, in a child directory, because '.' was removed from the search path. `require_relative` was added to give us that capability.

Comment: I don't think there's much difference between the semantics of using the commands - both work fine.

However your suggestion on require_relative worked a treat, I've managed to reconfigure my app to use that instead and it seems to be working better on ubuntu now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does doing `export RUBYOPT=rubygems` help?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to make a difference I'm afraid